# Como recuperar as categorias vinculadas a um post?

Tags: php, laravel-5

Subi no Github (https://github.com/fabiojaniolima/larablog-beta) um pequeno projeto em Laravel, algo bem inicial. Pretendo o mais breve possível arrumar as rotas, estruturar os métodos, etc.

Liberei este código prematuro pois me deparei com um problema que não estou conseguindo resolver sozinho. Explico logo abaixo.

Montei um esquema de Categorias, este esquema será utilizada pela tela de Biblioteca, Cursos e Posts. Já estou conseguindo cadastrar as categorias e também vincular um post a mais de uma categoria, bem como desfazer o relacionamento (post <=> categoria) ao excluir o post. O problema está no momento de editar um post, não estou conseguindo neste momento remontar toda a estrutura de categorias pre-selecionando as vinculadas ao post.

O método utilizado para editar o post está localizado em App\Http\Controllers\Painel\PostController:

```
public function edit(Post $post)
{
    $categorias = Categoria::all()->toHierarchy();

    return view('painel.posts.cad-edit', compact('post', 'categorias'));
}
```

Conheço Laravel a pouco tempo, logo não conheço muito bem seu funcionamento. Ao final deste projeto irei liberar o mesmo sobre uma licença MIT, bem como utilizar este para disponibilizar alguns de meus livros, artigos e cursos gratuitamente.

A ideia das categorias é algo parecido com: imgur.com/a/itX71

Comment: Pelo que vi do git hub tens uma relação de muitos para muitos entre post e categorias, isto vai ajudar: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many, https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships . O primeiro link ajuda-te a saber como obter os posts de cada categoria (e vice-versa) e o segundo é para fazeres update a essa relação, com `attach/detach`

Comment: Esse edit não seria para mostrar o registro na tela antes da alteração? `public function edit(Post $post)`?

Comment: Sim. Quero listar o post, bem como a categoria a qual ele está associado e todas as outras categorias cadastradas, permitindo que o "autor" altere a categoria associada. Algo parecido com o que existe no Wordpress: http://imgur.com/a/itX71

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer listar as categorias relacionadas ao post. Você pode chamar o método do model que diz quem são as categorias associadas a ele.

Tipo:

```
public function edit(Post $post)
{
    $categorias = Post::find($id)->categorias;

    return view('painel.posts.cad-edit', compact('post', 'categorias'));
}
```

desta maneira ele retornará as categorias relacionadas a este post em especifico!

Comment: quero listar todas mas marcando as relacionadas.

Comment: Então o que pode ser feito é você retornar todas as categorias com o Categorias:all() gerando um array com todas as categorias e fazer um for verificando se as categorias retornadas do Post estão contidas umas nas outras e fazer uma marcação, isso pode ser feito já diretamente na view, você retorna as listas e pimbas! Você pode usar o in_array do Php!